# Clear Linux file system after shutdown / start

Tags: filesystem, files, mint, history

I have very specific task. I need to clear the desktop, downloads, documents and so on after every shutdown or finish.

For example, if anyone downloads something using Google Chrome, he will work with it and then he'll shutdown the computer for next use.

And when second user sits for working on the computer, he'll find a clear file system without the data downloaded by the first user.

On Windows, I used to work with Returnil Virtual System, but it doesn't have support for Linux. Can anybody tell me if is it possible and, if so, how? I was also thinking of using Wine for this program, but  don't think it will be the best idea.

Comment: Is using a [Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) an option? If no, how about just using the guest account, which is cleared automatically?

Comment: And can I install programs from administrator for guest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [guest account](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html) for this. Add or remove programs from the admin account, then log in via the guest account. It is reset completely each time someone logs out of it, which is what you want.

Comment: And can I install programs from administrator for guest?